# Check if children elements (images) are loaded before executing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, load

I have a div which contains a number of images. I would like to check if all the images in this div are loaded before executing some code. I can't work it off the entire document as there are other things on the page which may take much longer to load.

How can I do this? jquery is available for use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should sue the [load event](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/)

```
$('img').load(function(){
   //here do what you need to do when the img is loaded
});
```

there are some caveats

> Caveats of the load event when used with images
>
> A common challenge developers attempt to solve using the .load()
>   shortcut is to execute a function when an image (or collection of
>   images) have completely loaded. There are several known caveats with
>   this that should be noted. These are:
>
> - It doesn't work consistently nor reliably cross-browser
> - It doesn't fire correctly in WebKit if the image src is set to the same src as before
> - It doesn't correctly bubble up the DOM tree
> - Can cease to fire for images that already live in the browser's cache

Comment: This is right but be careful though as the jQuery `load` method is quite unreliable. Make sure you test your script cross browser. +1

Comment: @BenCarey yes i added the "caveat" :)

Comment: I saw a second after I commented! :-)

Comment: We should all sue the load event! :P

Answer (score 0):

You can do sth like this:

```
var files = ['a.jpg','b.png']; //defines all assets needed

$.each(files,function(){
   var tmp = new Image();
   tmp.src = this; //creates a new dummy object
   tmp.on('load',function(){
   var i = files.indexOf(this);
      files.splice(i,1); //when dummy object has loaded it gets removed from array
      if (!files.length){ //when array is empty we're all set
         alert('Preloading done!');
      }
   });
});
```